# Earth Engine Gap filling null values over an imageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm attempting to run a function to automate the gap filling of nodata values in several imageCollections using focal mean, but somewhere I've taken the incorrect route. Need some help.

```
Map.setOptions('satellite')
Map.centerObject(chora, 11)

var bess =  = ee.ImageCollection("SNU/ESL/BESS/Rad/v1");
var aod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES");
var ndwi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MYD09GA_006_NDWI");

var vari = bess.select('RSDN_Daily').filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31');

function fill(image){
  ima = image.focal_mean(1, 'square', 'pixels', 20)
  imei = ima.blend(image)
  image = imei
  return image
}

print(fill(vari))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to invoke `fill()` for every image in your `vari` collection, as apposed to passing the whole collection to `fill()`. You use `map()` for that.

```
var filled = vari.map(fill)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6fe5a41e17705f0470069e5c8edbb855